# Matrix shapes are not aligned

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

When I try to multiply matrices using broadcating, I get an error when the matrices are in fact valid for multiplication.

```
x = np.random.randn(2)
y = np.random.randn(2, 3, 3)
x * y
```

It works if the shapes of the array are

```
x = np.random.randn(1)
y = np.random.randn(1, 3, 3)
x * y
```

What happened and why is this so?

Comment: when you random with shape `(1,)`, it consider `x` as a scalar, so it is normal if a matrix `A` multiply with a scale value`alpha`. Otherwise, shape `(2,)` will create a matrix which doesn't match with `(2,3,3)`. You can fix that by using this `x = np.random.randn(2,1,1)`

Comment: It's all about the first rule of broadcasting - add leading dimensions to match the `ndim`.  Or to put it another way, only leading 1's are automatic.  You have to explicitly add the trailing 1's if  you need those.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. The problem statment, desired behavior, analysis and all that are in the question and quite clear. Being new and not knowing how something works is not a crime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), dimensions line up on the right, not left. So the following shapes do not match:

```
      2
2, 2, 3
```

But if you did this instead, it would work:

```
x = np.random.randn(3)
y = np.random.randn(2, 3, 3)
```

The dimensions line up now:

```
      3
2, 2, 3
```

A dimension of 1 can be unambiguously expanded to any size, so your last example works like this:

```
      1
1, 3, 3
```

It is almost purely by coincidence, not because the two unit dimensions line up.

The details are spelled out in the [General Broadcasting Rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) section of the document linked in the beginning of this answer.

If you really wanted the leading dimensions to match up, there are a couple of ways to do so, depending on what you want. For example, you could generate the array to have the appropriate number of trailing dimensions:

```
x = np.random.randn(2, 1, 1)
```

Or you could reshape the array afterwards:

```
x = np.random.randn(2).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
```

Both could be done dynamically as well. For example, if you were to generate `y` first, you could do

```
x = np.random.randn(y.shape[0], *(1,) * (y.ndim - 1))
```

or

```
x = np.random.randn(y.shape[0]).reshape(-1, *(1,) * (y.ndim - 1))
```